# Trying to find a film with a political joke about pot and california

Tags: identify-this-movie

I watched a film that had the main protagonist attending a conference where the (iirc) American president was making a speech.

The speech referenced the politician doing different things and getting a number of votes from a specific states. As the joke progressed he would get more and more votes until the punch-line was something along the lines of 'smoked pot in college; California 20,000 votes'.

Please help me to find this film, it's driving me mad now!

Comment: Any idea of the age of the movie, even when you first saw it?

Comment: Mm, I would say that it was sometime between 1995 and now. My memory is telling me it went something like "You know, I had bacon his morning ... Main 1 vote. I did something elsewhere, Texas 30 votes. I smoked pot in college; California 2 million votes"

Comment: totally paraphrasing in the above comment you understand, just trying to represent the flow of the scene!

Comment: I'd like to help you too. Any extra detail could be useful :) Did you see the entire movie? Can you remember the plot? Its genre? Any big celebrity? Thanks.

Comment: Keen got it spot on; sadly had I known those details I should have found it on IMDB myself. All I remember was the pager and the pot comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The movie is *The Sum of All Fears*, and the full quote you're thinking of is:

> My beautiful wife, Julie, is from New Jersey. 15 electoral votes... and is, as you know, half Jewish. So we'll take Florida's 25 electoral votes and divide by 2. My daughter, Jeanie, is expecting her first child. If it's a girl, she will be named Virginia. 13 electoral votes. In fact, even if it's a boy, he'll be named Virginia. She reminds me that I have publicly acknowledged that as a young Marine officer in Vietnam, I did, on a handful of occasions, smoke marijuana. 
>   [pause] 
>   California. 54 electoral votes.

Source for the quote is [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0164184/), but I recognized the movie as I recently rewatched all the Jack Ryan movies.